# Prevent Google Charts from escaping apostrophes in a title of a chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm using google Bar Charts https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart. The titles for are stored in a database and some them contain apostrophes. Those apostrophes in the title are rendered as **&39**, for example "he's" ---> "he&39s"

I want apostrophes to be rendered normally.

I've found several solutions but none of them worked so far for such a simple task.

Any **working** solution?

**update:**

This is rendered properly, as `I'm goooood`

```
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("my_div"));
  chart.draw(data, {
    title: "I'm goooood",
    legend: {position: "none"},
  });
```

But this - not, it's ---> `I&#39;m goooood`

```
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("my_div"));
  chart.draw(data, {
    title: "<%= get_value_from_db() %>",
    legend: {position: "none"},
  });"
```

On other pages, without charts but text only, the "<%= get_value_from_db() %>" gets rendered correctly -- `I'm goooood`.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue but only with ' and " which get rendered as  "&39," or  "&34," .

As none of the above fixes worked for me, a quick and pretty dirty solution I've relied upon is using string.replace with the prime ( ′ ), and double prime ( ″ ) symbols - looped through a reasonable number of times.

```
<%= varName.replace("\'",'′').replace("\"",'″ ') %>
```

Also I think this error may have something to do with how Google Charts and EJS interact together as both the OP and I are using it and have this issue. (pure speculation)

Answer (score 0):

Use \ to escape '. Look at the example

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses', 'Profit'],
          ['2014', 1000, 400, 200],
          ['2015', 1170, 460, 250],
          ['2016', 660, 1120, 300],
          ['2017', 1030, 540, 350]
        ]);

        var options = {
          chart: {
            title: 'Company\'Performance',
            subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2014-2017',
          },
          bars: 'horizontal' // Required for Material Bar Charts.
        };

        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('barchart_material'));

        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="barchart_material" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

As you are getting tittle from db, you have to add \ before ' in title string using string manipulation.

Comment: it's not working for me, `I'm` is still rendered as `I&#39;m`

Comment: I think you are getting &#39; from db. Have you checked what you are getting? Use decoder to decode these and then pass to google charts.

Comment: updated.

in my db it's the correct value -- "I'm gooooood" because I can see it using a tool and via console and  also on other pages where I don't have charts -- it's rendered normally

Comment: Get value from <%= get_value_from_db() %> in some string and then escape using string manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a dom element to convert the ascii characters to readable text

```
function convertToText(ascii) {
  var tempDiv = document.createElement('DIV');
  tempDiv.innerHTML = ascii;
  return tempDiv.textContent || tempDiv.innerText || '';
}
```

in your options...

```
chart.draw(data, {
  title: convertToText("<%= get_value_from_db() %>"),
  legend: {position: "none"},
});
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', 'y'],
    ['A', 9],
    ['B', 30],
    ['C', 50],
    ['D', 70],
    ['E', 90]
  ]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, {
    title: convertToText('I&#39;m goooood'),
    legend: {position: 'none'},
  });

  function convertToText(ascii) {
    var tempDiv = document.createElement('DIV');
    tempDiv.innerHTML = ascii;
    return tempDiv.textContent || tempDiv.innerText || '';
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use decodeURI on the text.
My title comes from what the user has chosen from categories.
So, when I show the chart title, I do like this:

title: decodeURI(strCategory) + ' from ' + decodeURI(strInitialDate) + ' to ' + decodeURI(strEndDate)

My categories include, 'Alimentação', 'Feira/Sacolão' and others...
It works even on smartphones.

Added: Works with alerts also...

```
alert('Sem dados para o período de: ' + decodeURI(strInitialDate) + ' a ' + decodeURI(strEndDate))
```